# Remove repeated lines from a text file in order for phpMyAdmin to successfully insert SQL statements into database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a large text file full of INSERT SQL statements that I want to insert into a phpMyAdmin database. The problem I am having is that many of these INSERT statements within this file are identical, resulting in “Duplicate Key” error occuring. 
Is there a way to make phpMyAdmin ignore the repeated SQL statements? I have tried running the file through a .vbs script that removes duplicate lines but it failed to deliver. 
Logic that I am thinking of so far is the following:
Run the file through a script that removes duplicate lines.
Find a solution in which phpMyAdmin ignores repeated lines. 
Has anyone got any other ideas or suggestions on how I could solve this problem?

Comment: MySQL has something like INSERT IGNORE. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is by using INSERT IGNORE statement, but you will not know which record is duplicate.

another way, by create new table like 'table2' with no primary key or unique key, insert all the data into it, then INSERT IGNORE to your main table before, and compare which row are duplicate. Or maybe you can use the COUNT() function to get the duplicate row by.